# Python email library does not add all MIME text parts

Tags: python, python-2.7, email

I added piece of code in my program. Why is it not working?

Below is the sample code:

```
wrapper = MIMEMultipart('mixed')

text1 = "this is a sample text"

text2 = "this is a sample msg"

part1 = MIMEText(text1, "plain")

part2 = MIMEText(text2, "plain")

wrapper.attach(part1)

wrapper.attach(part2)
```

output:

Part1 value is coming in msg body but part2 value is coming as attachment in mail. Why part2 value is not coming in msg body?

Answer (score 0):

Send the message as a string. Try the below code. It works for me:

```py
wrapper = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
text1 = "this is a sample text"
text2 = "this is a sample msg"

#change the message type to html type
part1 = MIMEText(text1, "html")
part2 = MIMEText(text2, "html")

#create the message to send
wrapper.attach(part1)
wrapper.attach(part2)

#finally send the message by converting it to string
server.sendmail(from, recipients, wrapper.as_string())
```